# What do these form attributes mean?

Tags: php, html

```
<form method="get" action="index.php" target="abc" name="SearchForm" id="SearchForm">
```

on clicking `submit` we get to `index.php` where we can access typed information using `GET` method. What does `target`, `name` and `id` mean here? and what do they do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form 
    method="get"        -- submit method (post|get)
    action="index.php"  -- page to submit form to
    target="abc"        -- frame id to target. ex: <iframe id="abc" src="myframe.html">
    name="SearchForm"   -- name of the form, used with client-side scripting
    id="SearchForm"     -- CSS id of the form. ex: #SearchForm { font-size: large; }
                           - used for client-side scripting (javascript)
                           - must be unique. <div id="abc"><p id="abc"> = invalid
/>
```

Comment: id isn't just for CSS. It uniquely identifies the element on a page. There can be multiple names on a page and multiple classes on a page, but only one id.

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search would answer that questions.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp

Comment: I support the search tip, however: [W3Schools is harming the community with inaccurate information.](http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: Wow. What an interesting read. I have generally only used it for a quick explanation or refresher of some elements attributes. In that case: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/form